# Arrange the integers $1,2,\dots,n$ in a row such that the number of times that an integer is bigger than the previous integer is $m$.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Let $F(m,n)$ to be the number of ways to arrange the integers
>   $1,2,\dots,n$ in a row such that the number of times that an integer
>   is bigger than the previous integer is $m$.
>
> Find a recurrence relation for $F(n,m)$

**My attempt:**

Let's look at the position of the integer $n$, there are $4$ options for it:

1. It's last in the row, therfore if we take it out, we remain with $F(n-1,m-1)$
2. It's first in the row, therfore if we take it out, we remain with $F(n-1,m)$
3. It's in between two numbers which are in ascending order, therfore if we take it out, we remain with $F(n-1,m)$
4. It's in between two numbers which are in descending order, therfore if we take it out, we remain with $F(n-1,m-1)$

Hence,

$F(n,m)=2\cdot F(n-1,m)+2\cdot F(n-1,m-1)$

But it is not the right answer.

Where is my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider case 3. How many locations in the string does this describe? (likewise case 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In options $3$ and $4$ there are many places where the neighboring numbers are in that order, so there should be a coefficient involving $m$.  Think of the number of places to add $n$ in.

For $3$, there are $m$ places you can insert $n$.  For $4$ there are $n-m-2$ places to insert $n$, so the recurrence should be 
$$F(n,m)=(m+1)F(n-1,m)+(n-m)F(n-1,m-1)$$

Comment: Thanks! how do you know it is $m$ and $n-m-2$ places?

Comment: Just like your logic.  If you start with $F(n,m)$ and $n$ is in an increasing space, there are still $m$ increasing spaces when you remove it.  You can put it in any of those.  If $n$ is in a decreasing space, there are $m-1$ increasing spaces when you remove it.  There are a total of $n-2$ spaces when you remove it, so there are $n-m-1$ decreasing spaces to put it in.  Note the update by $1$ because we need to add in case 1